# Simple code not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]I am using sublime-text 2 editör and chromium web browser in Ubuntu.This very simple code not working but when I only write alert("test") within script tags it is working But this simple code not working now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Scroll Activated Animation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
      alert("test");
    });
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    #test{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="test">Click here</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

There is no problem with jquery source code.Because as I told above only alert is working

Image Path:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure , the jQuery path is correct?

Comment: Could you please provide us the fiddle

Comment: Have you tried `alert("test");` within `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: @Zim84 this is also not working I tried

Comment: @Pranav C Balan Yes path correct only alert worked

Comment: @Sai Deepak I dont get it what you mean

Comment: Just try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/fmr2Lnj5/

Comment: @Tank Akyüz if you say it is not working what I have proposed to you, this means that jQuery is NOT working. So you have to check that jQuery is actually loaded...

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz "Because as I told above only alert is working": what do you mean? That the alert code works outside of the click function?

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz Alert works always buddy, irrespective of jQuery.

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz please post the code when it was working separately?

Comment: Check error in console. I guess you aren't running any server and so `file` protocol is assumed by chrome. Anyway, this isn't suitable question on SO, learn how to debug javascript and then ask relevantr question if you cannot fix yourself error

Comment: There are 2 errors... show em to us! :)

Comment: I am really noob sorry and really interesting this code is not working

Comment: $ is not defined ooppsy....

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz click console to show the error

Comment: @Pekka the problem is about permission thank you anyway

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz happy coding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if the path to jQuery correct. In your case, the path should be this way:

```sql
+ jquery-2.1.4.js
+ some_folder
| + some_other_folder
| | + index.html     ----- This is your file.
```

The code you have given is **perfectly right**. You have two options:

1. Correct the path of jQuery.
2. Use a CDN: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js`

So the second option would be adding the following instead of what you have as a reference for jQuery in your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: I edited my answer with picture of path.Please look at the pictures

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz Looks perfect. Press F12 and show me the output.

Comment: Check my last picture

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz Nice click on the red 2 on top right corner.

Comment: Or click on `Console` in the dev tools. @TarıkAkyüz.

Comment: look at my first picture bro

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz Your stuff looks like the `jquery-2.1.4.js` has some issues. Try right clicking on the file and click on properties. Use the file permissions as `777`.

Comment: Yes the problem is about permission.Now this is working very well

Comment: @TarıkAkyüz Glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle with your code and it seems to work.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
      alert("test");
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1ygxkx24/

Do you get any error in your browser's command line?

The problem is probably related to the import of the jquery library: the fact that alert works anyway doesn't mean a lot since it's pure js and not jquery related.

Comment: who the hell is downvoting this answer? Add a comment and help nowhere improve her post if you think it is unworthy...

Comment: This is not really an answer, more of a request for more information - should probably have been a comment (PS. not my downvote - appears to be gone now)

Comment: I've updated it a bit. He's saying that it should work because the alert works anyway outside of the jquery function.

Comment: @nowhere alert dont need jquery. OP problem is Jquery is not working. Maybe path is incorrect. as what Praveen suggested

Comment: @Pekka exactly that's what we were trying to explain :) But without the console errors it's hard to debug here...